# Installing OpenCV 3.1 on OS X El Capitan using Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5

I have looked for a proper way to install OpenCV, but all I can find are people fudging around with Python 2.old or virtualenv or other things that are utterly irrelevant. I just want be able to run `import cv2` without any import errors.

How do I install OpenCV on OS X 10.11 for use with Python 3.5.1?

Answer (score 3):

For me the only working way was using conda:

`conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3`

and then import it using `import cv2`

Answer (score 2):

We can install opencv3 for Python3(Python3.5) for Mac OS X with homebrew.

First, install homebrew:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

You can see the details for how to install homebrew. http://brew.sh

If you don't install Python3, install python3:

`brew install python3`

Then install opencv3 for python3:

`brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

Finally, maybe you will link site-packages of opencv3 to the site-packages of Python3:

In the follow command, `/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` is the directory of opencv3's site-packages, `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` is the directory of Python3.5's site-packages. Maybe you should change the two to your own directories.

`echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv3.pth`

Answer (score 0):

For mac, i would suggest using `homebrew` (http://brew.sh), the best package manager for osx; after you install it, you can simply use -from a terminal-:

```
brew search xxx
```

To search for a package 'xxx'; in this case, try `brew search opencv` and you will get the results `opencv` and `opencv3`, then just install `opencv3` with:

```
brew install opencv3
```

And that's it, it will install all the required dependencies (which are listed if you use `brew info opencv3`).

Any question, just ask.

Comment: I did that, but apparently my installation of Python 3.5.1 didn't get the memo. I still can't use OpenCV there.

Comment: A simple `ImportError: No module named cv2`.

Comment: Try `import cv`, `import opencv`, `import opencv2, if still not working and the package was correctly installed, you got a problem with the `site-packages` folder maybe; are you sure you are using the correct python version?

Comment: None of these are working. How do I check what's wrong with the site-packages folder and what do you mean by "correct Python version"? I'm not switching to anything else, it either works with 3.5.1 or it's crap.

Comment: Just tried removing and installing opencv3 with Homebrew again, this time in verbose mode. Turns out that Homebrew installs OpenCV3 for Python 2.7, which is utterly useless. How do I get it for a modern Python?

Comment: That's what i mean when i said to check the python version :).

Install opencv again from homebrew, but this time add the flag `--with-python3`, ie: `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

(You can see all the flags for package xxx if you do `brew info xxx`)

Comment: Did that, didn't work. I still can't `import cv2` in Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5. OpenCV's absolutely lackluster installation docs are not helping.